# GWT Datagrid slow scroll due to css rendering

Tags: performance, css, gwt, scroll

I have a big `DataGrid` (70 columns, 500 rows). The problem I've encountered is that when I apply some css to render the cells of the grid in a specific manner, the performance of scrolling suffers. I override the default css of `DataGrid` 
and added the below css rules that cause the problem

```
.dataGridHeader, .dataGridHeader div, .dataGridHeader div, .dataGridCell div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

What I want to do with the above is clear. I just want the cell to remain unchanged even when the text is bigger and just show `...` for the text that is not visible.

The problem is a significant delay when scrolling when using Chrome. I've also tried IE and Firefox, and the results were fine. No delay at all.
Can I do something to boost the performance of Chrome?

My question is about css. I know that the grid is big and paging can be used, to reduce some load. This is for a test case and I need only answers that have to do with css.

I'm using GWT 2.5.1 and Chrome 43.0.2357.81

If someone wants to reproduce just download the example the [official site](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) 
and add enough columns and rows to stress it a little bit. Override the default css and add the above.

Comment: Haven't used `DataGrid` for a while as I found it horrifically slow compared to `CellTable`. Does `CellTable` run any better?

Comment: To be honest I haven't. I need the behavior of datagrid regarding the scrolling (fixed header). Seeing the source code of the two widgets I haven's spotted any big differences apart from the fact that datagrid has the scrolling mechanism I need. Thanks for the comment though.